# Keytool's -storepass vs. -keypass -- Why 2 passwords?

Tags: android, security, keytool

I understand that the `-keypass` option is for "the password for the key" and that the `-storepass` option is for "a password for the keystore".

I don't understand, however, why two passwords are needed.

What scenarios are there for requiring 2 passwords: One for the store (file, in my case) and one for the key.

Comment: Your `storepass` password is to verify the integrity of a keystore/truststore. Your `keypass` password is actually to decrypt a private or secret key. Yes you can still just "view" public certificates without inputting any passwords but.....you won't be able verify their integrity. So what's the point?

Comment: Another way to think of it is like `storepass` is like a hidden symmetric key for a "keystore/truststore" MAC (message authentication), while `keypass` is like the actual *decryption key itself*. So the latter actually protects the private/secret keys stored inside.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is due to how Java handles keystores so it's not an Android specific issue. The reason though is because access to a store such as adding/viewing trust relationships is a separate task from creating and signing keys/certs.

In short, you may trust someone to view/update your keystore but not sign things with a key you store in the keystore. Plus, keys could be stored in multiple keystores and you want your keys locked down individually.

Comment: Thanks. At first I thought this feature of 2 passwords is really useful for teams but doesn't make a difference for single-person development "team". Then I read the last sentence in your answer and realized it could be useful for a single developer as well. Thanks++ (will accept shortly).

Answer (score 19):

Keytool uses storepass and keypass for different purposes.

storepass is used to access the key store

keypass is used to access the particular key pair's private key.

However, a  password  should  not  be specified  on  a  command  line or in a script unless it is for testing purposes, or you are on a secure system.