# What's the difference between Key store password and Key password in Android Sign Certification?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on Android Stuido to generate a signed certification, but from the New Key Store option, I need to create two passwords for this certification. Do you know where the difference between them is?

[image]

Comment: IMO you can read here [Signing in Release Mode](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html). I think key store is like a container that contains private key, both need to be kept secure. So need 2 passwords. You can read `Securing Your Private Key` section at that link

Comment: this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19876060/3983054

Comment: related: [Keytool's -storepass vs. -keypass — Why 2 passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954459/keytools-storepass-vs-keypass-why-2-passwords)

Answer (score 49):

**Keystore** is a binary file that contains a set of private keys.

**Private key** represents the entity to be identified with the app, such as a person or a company.

So Keystore password is used to open a keystore and simple password is password of private entity stored in keystore file..!!
[image: check here]

Comment: When using jarsigner it only asks for one password - I assume this is the key store password so why does Android Studio's Build -> Generate Signed APK require another password?

Comment: @Marc : Are we talking about Android application ?

Comment: Yes, we signed our Android .apk app with jarsigner and one password. Android Studio "demands" two.

Comment: Am I correct that both the keystore password and the simple password only exists on your local computer, but neither gets sent with the app to the app store?

Answer (score 9):

Key Store password is like master password of other key's
Multiple key pairs can be store within a key store.
when you try to reuse that key android studio will ask you for key store password.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggest the key store is a collection of private and public keys. One can have multiple pairs of public and private keys within a key store.

In simpler terms key store is the directory which holds the key.