# Flutter Android Release: Got confused between keystore password VS. key password

Tags: android, flutter

So I'm generating a key for my Android Play store release using a command as below. It asked for a password and confirm the password. I guess this is called the key password.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/my_key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Using this command to build a .aab bundle

```
flutter build appbundle --no-shrink --verbose
```

Then using command to get an APK

```
java -jar bundletool-all-0.15.0.jar build-apks --bundle=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab --output=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.apks \
--ks=~/my_key.jks \
--ks-pass=pass:<...> \
--ks-key-alias=key \
--key-pass=pass:<...>
```

This is where I got confused? I see both `ks-pass` and `key-pass`, not sure which is which.

Comment: this thread can help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304046/whats-the-difference-between-key-store-password-and-key-password-in-android-sig
Using the keytool genkey command also prompt you 2 times to enter password,
1. Enter Keystore password
2. Enter key password

Comment: For more detail please check official documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk

Comment: @LEWCC No, I only get chance to enter "Enter keystore password" & "Re-enter new password".

Comment: you could build an apk directly with `flutter build apk`, when releasing to the play store, it's important to realize that the google play store does in most cases app signing on its own (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play)