# java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, keystore, keytool, client-certificates

I ran following commands to generate a keystore, certificate and a truststore:

1. keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias clientcertalias -dname "CN=Local,OU=Department,O=Company,L=City,ST=State,C=US" -keystore keystore.jks  -storepass "clientpassword1" -keypass "clientpassword2"
2. keytool -export -alias clientcertalias -file client.cer -keystore  keystore.jks  -storepass "clientpassword1"
3. keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias clientcertalias -file client.cer -keystore  keystore.jks -storepass "serverpass" -noprompt;

When I try to start my tomcat server, it gives above mentioned exception. But when I keep "storepass" and "keypass" of point 1 same, my server starts smoothly. What is significance of the two passwords? Why do we have to keep them same?

Comment: Neither Tomcat nor JSSE can actually cope with key passwords that are different from the keystore password.

Comment: This question might be answered by this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5954459/618465