# Spring boot 2.2 and setting HTTPS. Why two password as needed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, https, spring-boot-2

All is into the question. I'm using spring boot 2.2 and I follow the documentation to set HTTPS ([see the doc chapter here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-ssl)). In this example there is two parameter to define the key password. But in fact the password of my key need to do the same in that to parameters to work... **An idea about why spring define two password entries ?**

Thanks in advance for explainations ;)

Additional informations: I have the same comportement with .p12 and .jks key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not spring Specific but a standard one.

Keystore is a binary file that contains a set of private keys.

Private key represents the entity to be identified with the app, such as a person or a company.

See this thread : [Keytool's -storepass vs. -keypass -- Why 2 passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954459/keytools-storepass-vs-keypass-why-2-passwords)

And

[What's the difference between Key store password and Key password in Android Sign Certification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304046/whats-the-difference-between-key-store-password-and-key-password-in-android-sig/32304393)

Comment: Thanks Alien. All is on you links.